# Simulating the iOS Assistive Gesture feature in Android

Tags: android, accessibility, gesture

I was wondering if there was a way to implement the same type of functionality of iOS's Assistive Gesture in Android. I know that actions can be performed on behalf of the user through the AccessibilityService, but is it possible to use the AccessibilityService in the same manner?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What functionality are you trying to achieve?

Comment: From what I've read, it's possible for the AccessibilityService to perform actions on behalf of a user (click, long press, etc...). What I'm trying to figure is if it's possible to perform those same operations in another application. I've played around with this app called AutoInput in the Google Play store that can do the same thing, and I'm trying to come up with a base implementation with the same functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want [AccessibilityNodeInfo.performAction(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo.html#performAction(int)). This allows an accessibility service to perform an action (click, long-press, etc.) on a view or virtual view in the app hierarchy.

To do so, your AccessibilityService will need to be set up to retrieve window content. You can read more about this in the "Retrieving window content" section of the [AccessibilityService documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html).

Comment: I'll look into that. Thanks!